# Decrease list difference via swaps

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, extremal-combinatorics

There are four lists, each with $100$ numbers in $[0,1]$. You want to perform as few swaps between pairs of numbers as possible, so that the difference between the sums of numbers in any two lists becomes at most $1$. What is the largest number of swaps that you may have to perform?

A worst case seems to be when two lists are all $1$ and the other two lists are all $0$, which needs $100$ swaps. A method for achieving the goal (difference $\le 1$) is that, as long as the goal is not met, we swap a largest number in a largest-sum list with a smallest number in a smallest-sum list. This always terminates because after the swap, both lists have a larger sum than the previous sum of the smaller-sum list. But does it always terminate after at most $100$ swaps?

Comment: When you say " so that the difference between the sums of numbers in any two lists becomes at most 1", do you mean the sums of the same rank ?

Comment: @JeanMarie (I believe that) It's the sum of all the numbers in the set. There is no inherent "ranking/ordering" of the set.

Comment: Yes, Calvin Lin's understanding is right.

Comment: Isn't this pretty trivial to prove? If we call A,B,C,D the sums of the 4 lists ordered from least to most, then (D-A) + (C-B) is at most 200. When this value is 2 or more, a swap will always decrease the value by 2, as you add 1 to A and subtract 1 from D, at each step

Comment: @Cruncher the entries of the list are real numbers, not integers.

Comment: @BobKrueger Ah okay, thanks!. That makes the proof harder, but pretty sure the result is still the same. It means that you can't always decrease the value by 2, but in the cases where you can't decrease by a very high value, it means the lists are already close to similar. More rigor is of course needed.

Comment: You can probably make a greedy argument to show that any case is at least as quick as the worst case example with a replacement argument

Comment: I have crossposted the question at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/460371/136218).